# Time exceeded in function

Tags: php

Error Output: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

I think there isn't any wrong thing in there. What is wrong?

```
    function advancedSearchAgeOption($selectName, $selectID, $firstValue, $lastValue) {
    $selectBox.='<select name="'.$selectName.'" id="'.$selectID.'">';
    for ($i=$firstValue; $i=$lastValue; $i++) {
        $selectBox.='<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    $selectBox.='</select>';
    return $selectBox;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace this line:

```
for ($i=$firstValue; $i=$lastValue; $i++) {
```

With this:

```
for ($i=$firstValue; $i<=$lastValue; $i++) {
```

The second expression should evaluate to `true` for every `$i` until the end.

Comment: Oh thanks, I haven't seen that. Thanks!